# Make text transparent in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, layers, clipping-mask

I have two layers of text and a blue background.
I want to make the "SERIEB2" text transparent in order to see the background and "cut" the text below.
How can I make it via clipping mask in Photoshop[image]?

Comment: Do you want to cut the red text entirely from the white, leaving a hole, or do you still want the red text to be visible with partial transparency.

Comment: I'd like to leave an hole where the red text is

Answer (score 3):

Here's one method to make the red text cut through the white, leaving a hole . . .

1. Covert your background layer into a Smart Object (this will make it easier to edit afterwards)
2. Type the white text on a layer above the Smart Object
3. Type the red text on a layer above that
4. Duplicate the Smart Object layer, and drag it to the top of the layers
5. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click between the two top layers to clip them

[image]

6. Now if you want to change the background, double click the Smart Object to open it, and paste another image in there, close and Save the Smart Object. Back in the main document, both Smart Objects will update automatically.

[image]

Note: All text is still editable, and the layers are all still moveable. Also, you don't have to use Smart Objects to do this, but if you change the background, you'll have to remove the top layer, duplicate the new background and do the clip again. Using Smart Objects avoids unnecessary repetition.

Another method, thanks to a suggestion from @joojaa - is to add a knockout layer style/blending option, set the Red text layer fill to 0%, and group the text layers.

[image]

Comment: You can use knockout layers you know. Way simpler less layers too.

Comment: @joojaa - Yes, there are probably a couple of ways to do this.  Why don't you write an answer showing your method?

Comment: No computer at summer cottage.

Comment: @joojaa - I've added a screenshot for your alternative method, and given you credit for the suggestion.